# Chromium kiosk mode, able to launch via command line but does nothing in a bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, chromium, kiosk-mode

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.1 and trying to get a script working to launch chromium in kiosk mode. When I run the command:

snap run chromium --window-size=1920,1080 --kiosk --window-position=0,0 http://google.com &

Everything works just as I would expect it to, however if I put it into a script nothing happens and I get no output. I have the following script that I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run this script in display 0 - the monitor
export DISPLAY=:0

# Hide the mouse from the display
unclutter &

# If Chromium crashes (usually due to rebooting), clear the crash flag so we don't have the annoying warning bar
sed -i 's/"exited_cleanly":false/"exited_cleanly":true/' /honme/rooster/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Preferences
sed -i 's/"exit_type":"Crashed"/"exit_type":"Normal"/' /honme/rooster/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/Preferences

# Run Chromium and open tabs
snap run chromium --window-size=1920,1080 --kiosk --window-position=0,0 http://google.com &
```

When my original script failed I tried to run this script to test bash and it worked no problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, this worked"
```

So finally I tried to eliminate as much as possible and ran this script but again got no output and nothing happened:

```
#!/bin/bash

snap run chromium --window-size=1920,1080 --kiosk --window-position=0,0 http://google.com &
```

I am running Ubuntu on a HP t730 thin client that has a AMD RX-427BB cpu with 4 gb of ram and a 64 gb M.2 ssd. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Problem solved! My issue was I was using the wrong display variable. Changing the display variable to 0.0 instead of 0 in my original script fixed the issue. Silly mistake but glad I figured it out. Hope this helps someone else, 'echo $DISPLAY' output the correct variable and from there it was as simple as updating the script.